# Passing data between controllers/directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-components

I understand that this question has been answered and using a Service is the way to go, but I am a lost how to implement it. And would really appreciate some guidance.

I am trying to achieve this in the [Blur-Admin](https://github.com/akveo/blur-admin) framework.

The structure is as follows:

At the top, there is dashboard.module.js:

```
    (function () {
  'use strict';

      angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages.dashboard', [])
          .config(routeConfig);

      /** @ngInject */
      function routeConfig($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('dashboard', {
              url: '/dashboard',
              templateUrl: 'app/pages/dashboard/dashboard.html',
              title: 'Dashboard',
              sidebarMeta: {
                icon: 'ion-android-home',
                order: 0,
              },
            });
      }

    })();
```

And then dashboard.html is defined with elements.

```
    <div class="row">
         <dashboard-line-chart></dashboard-line-chart>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <dashboard-todo></dashboard-todo>
    </div>
...
...
```

After that, each of these elements are written using directives:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages.dashboard')
        .directive('dashboardLineChart', dashboardLineChart);

    /** @ngInject */
    function dashboardLineChart() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            controller: 'DashboardLineChartCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'app/pages/dashboard/dashboardLineChart/dashboardLineChart.html'
        };
    }
})();
```

And then the corresponding Controller as:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages.dashboard')
      .controller('DashboardLineChartCtrl', DashboardLineChartCtrl);

  /** @ngInject */
  function DashboardLineChartCtrl(baConfig, layoutPaths, baUtil) {...}
```

**What I would like to do is to share data between two such controllers.** 
For example:

```
function DashboardLineChartCtrl(baConfig, layoutPaths, baUtil, sharedData) {...}
```

and

```
function DashboardDataReceiver(baConfig, layoutPaths, baUtil, sharedData) {...}
```

If Services are the way to go, where should I define the service?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding the question, but just as you've done with your directives and controllers you simply create a `.service`.

Comment: @Lex Thanks. But what I am confused is, "where" to create the service? Can I create it in any one of the modules?

Comment: Yep. When you use `angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages.dashboard')` without the empty array parameter you're simply defining a new object on the existing app module. So just add `angular.module('BlurAdmin.pages.dashboard').service('sharedData', SharedData);` and then write your `SharedData` function just like the controller functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instance you can define a new service factory with a getter and a setter like this:

```
app.factory('sharedData', function () {
    var x = "";
    return {
        'getX': function () { return x; },
        'setX': function (newVal) { x = newVal; }
    }
});
```

Next you have to inject your service into your controllers as you written.
At last you can set and fetch your data via the service in the controllers such as:

```
sharedData.setX("some string"); // to set the x var into service with "some string"
sharedDate.getX(); // to get the x var content (in this case, "some string")
```

Quoting Angular Js docs:

> AngularJS services are:
>
> Lazily instantiated – AngularJS only instantiates a service when an
>   application component depends on it.
>
> Singletons – Each component
>   dependent on a service **gets a reference to the single instance**
>   generated by the service factory.

That means that you can define variables and update their values into the factory instance and access it from every controller in which you've injected it.